# AngularJS ng-repeat orderBy date for ascending sorting not working

Tags: angularjs, sorting

```
                                <li ng-repeat="item in a.b.c | orderBy:'item.date'">

                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"> item1-2015</a>


                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" >item2-2015</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

Date I am getting from JSON.Like 2015,i have other values with different years.I need to sort it in an ascending way.OrderBy is not working.Any way around?

In controller,$scope.a.b.c=[];

MY JSON is:

```
{
    "sort" : [
    {
        "name" : "xyz",
        "date" : "01-02-2001"
    },
    {
        "name" : "pqr",
        "date" : "01-02-2002"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is `a.b.c` an object or an array? Only arrays are sortable.

Comment: what is the structure of the "item" object? Does it have a 'Date' property? ``{ ... Date: '2005' }``

Comment: @ItamarL. yeah.have shared JSON structure above.

Comment: Shouldnt date be more specific? `orderBy:'a.b.c.Date'"` or whatever your `$scope` is

Comment: Did you try "date" instead of "Date"? I assume you are iterating over the "sort" property inside the object.

Comment: Yeah,that was jus a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQGBJwzGhm0oEWWNeU0R) with your solution. Note that it will order the dates like a string. If you want it to compare properly you will need to convert them to Date().

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    "sort" : [
    {
        "name" : "xyz",
        "date" : "01-02-2003"
    },
    {
        "name" : "pqr",
        "date" : "01-02-2002"
    }
    ]
}
});
```

and the html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data.sort | orderBy:'date'">
    {{ item.name }} - {{ item.date }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah,doing the same.Not working.Do i need to use toString()?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this  `<li ng-repeat="item in a.b.c | orderBy:'item.date'">`

use this `<li ng-repeat="item in a.b.c.sort | orderBy:'date'">`

it will work i guess. [ I assume a.b.c as your object and inside it sort as your array.]